# Proper format for PHP html email

Tags: php, html, email

```
$email="jason@home.net";

$message= "CALLERS NAME: ".$values["CallName"]."\r\n";
$message="CALLERS STREET ADDRESS: ".$values["CallStNo"]."\r\n";
$message="STREET DIRECTION: ".$values["CallStDir"]."\r\n";
$message="CALLERS STREET NAME: ".$values["CallStreet"]."\r\n";
$message="ISSUE CALLER IS CALLING ABOUT: ".$values["CallIssue"]."\r\n";
$message="ADDITIONAL INFORMATION: ".$values["CallMisc"]."\r\n"; 
$message="CALLERS PHONE NUMBER: ".$values["CallPhone"]."\r\n";
$message="DATE OF CALL: ".$values["date"]."\r\n";
$message="PERSON WHO TOOK PHONE CALL: ".$values["dataentry"]."\r\n"; 
$message="CURRENT STATUS OF CALL: ".$values["status"]."\r\n";

$subject="Call from Citizen";

 runner_mail(array('to' => $email, 'subject' => $subject, 
  'htmlbody' => $message, 'charset' => 'UTF-8'));
```

When I build this it only sends an email with the last line from the message $message="CURRENT STATUS OF CALL: ".$values["status"]."\r\n";

and the value.

do I need to wrap the message so I get all the fields populated in the email?

Comment: After the first `$message=` use `$message .=`. Read the documentation: http://www.php.net//manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Comment: You're overwriting your variable each time.

Comment: Use `$message .="...` for all your variables EXCEPT the first one. The dot is a concatenation character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've set and RESET `$message` several times. Leave the first `$message` as is (the CALLERS name one) and for the others, set it to `$message .=`

You should also avoid using quotations for both the variables and the echo as you otherwise risk re-opening the echo for the variable call. Change the variable calls to single quotes like so.

```
$email="jason@home.net";

$message = "CALLERS NAME: ".$values['CallName']."\r\n";
$message .="CALLERS STREET ADDRESS: ".$values['CallStNo']."\r\n";
$message .= "STREET DIRECTION: ".$values['CallStDir']."\r\n";
$message .= "CALLERS STREET NAME: ".$values['CallStreet']."\r\n";
$message .= "ISSUE CALLER IS CALLING ABOUT: ".$values['CallIssue']."\r\n";
$message .= "ADDITIONAL INFORMATION: ".$values['CallMisc']."\r\n"; 
$message .= "CALLERS PHONE NUMBER: ".$values['CallPhone']."\r\n";
$message .= "DATE OF CALL: ".$values['date']."\r\n";
$message .= "PERSON WHO TOOK PHONE CALL: ".$values['dataentry']."\r\n"; 
$message .= "CURRENT STATUS OF CALL: ".$values['status']."\r\n";

$subject="Call from Citizen";

 runner_mail(array('to' => $email, 'subject' => $subject, 
  'htmlbody' => $message, 'charset' => 'UTF-8'));
```

Comment: thank you for the quick replies, that works great. I must be missing something else as well. The data is in the email now, but \r\n are not putting what I thought were carriage returns. I would like the "CALLERS NAME:: to be bold, then the data, then a carriage return, then the next line of data, if that makes sense

Comment: @user3325169 As you're sending an HTML e-mail, you could use <br /> instead of \r\n